# OpenGL Context with Multiple Devices (Monitors)

Tags: windows, opengl, glut, multiple-monitors

In OpenGL I implicitly create a graphics context with something like GLUT when I create a window.  Suppose I drag my window into a monitor driven by a different video card (e.g. Intel embedded graphics on one and NVidia on another).  *Who renders the window?* I.e. which device runs the graphics pipeline for each of the cases below.

The `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` seems to always return the primary display (where the GLUT window was created) even if I drag the window fully into one window or the other. (I am guessing it all gets done by the primary...) *Can someone help me understand this?*

[image]

Note, using Windows 10, GLUT, OpenGL, but I ask the questions in general if it matters.

Comment: Are you talking about the general case where Nvidia's [Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) is *not* in effect?

Comment: Related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540194/opengl-and-multiple-gpus-general-possibility)

Answer (score 0):

GL knows nothing about windows, only about contexts. GL renders to the framebuffer in the current context.

You may code a way of asking the OS about where a window is, and use two context, and set as current the proper one depending on OS answer.

Comment: Yes, I assume each Window has a context or there is global one (GLUT). What confuses me is that each Window might have a different resolution etc... So somehow any graphics context must be able to draw on any of the monitors (devices). Is that right?

Comment: You create a context on a display device.  Its driver manages presentation behind the scenes.